# How to organize codeception tests in subfolders, and have one codecept.conf.js pointing to the whole folder schema

Tags: javascript, codeceptjs

I'm having issues, creating subfolders in my './acceptance_tests.js/*_tests.js' pathname within my codecept config.

I.e. My codecept.conf.js looks like this:

```
  exports.config = {
  tests: './acceptance_tests/*_test.js',
  output: './output' ....
```

I can run tests no problem that are within acceptance_test file path when the conf.js file is set to this. When I try to create a sub-folder to organize my tests i.e. acceptance_test > account_test > (tests)
or
acceptance_test > registration_test > (tests).

I am unable to call those tests, since the conf file is looking for all '*test.js' file within the acceptance_test folder.

I can change the path in the conf file to explicitly point to each subfolder, but it seems there must be a better way to do this. Since I would have to change the file path each time I wanted to run tests in another subfolder.

I have tried to point it to

```
'./acceptance_tests/randome_subfolder_Name/*_test.js'

'*_test.js'

'./acceptance_tests/*/*_test.js'
```

But cant seem to get it to run all subfolders or tests within those subfolders sitting within acceptance_test folder. I have tried manually calling out the whole path when running the test like so

```
Npm run codeceptjs  './acceptance_tests/random_subfolder_Name/andomTest_test.js'
```

And that doesn't work either. But the moment I take that test and drop it in the parent folder of acceptance_test - it does work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the config file you can specify it to look through subfolders with this

```
exports.config = {
tests: './acceptance_tests/**/*_test.js',
output: './output' ....
```

With the

```
'**'
```

spanning through all subfolders under acceptance_tests

Answer (score 0):

you can run tests from any folder if you select config file manually, for example:

```
npx codeceptjs run --grep "test name" --config=tests/codecept.conf.js
```

in my case config file for all tests is located in the tests folder